# Closest record for a series of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I know that to get the closest record prior to a date I can use the query:

```
select * 
from results 
where resulttime = (select max(resulttime) 
                    from results 
                    where some_id = 15 
                      and resulttime < '2012-07-27');
```

But I need to do this for a series of days, so that I know the closest record for each day. Any ideas?

The series of days would be generated by `generate_sequence()`.

The closest prior record may be in a prior day to what we want the value for, but still need to be returned.

Comment: What are your data types - `date` or `timestamp`? Define "closest" exactly. How do you provide the series of days? As dates in a tables, one date per row?

Comment: They are of type timestamp. "Closest record prior" is defined as the first record prior to the date given. This does potentially include a record on a previous day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be simplest & fastest with a `LEFT JOIN` and `DISTINCT ON`:

```
WITH x(search_ts) AS (
    VALUES
     ('2012-07-26 20:31:29'::timestamp)              -- search timestamps
    ,('2012-05-14 19:38:21')
    ,('2012-05-13 22:24:10')
    )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (x.search_ts)
       x.search_ts, r.id, r.resulttime
FROM   x
LEFT   JOIN results r ON r.resulttime <= x.search_ts -- smaller or same
-- WHERE some_id = 15                                -- some condition?
ORDER  BY x.search_ts, r.resulttime DESC;
```

Result (dummy values):

```
search_ts           | id     | resulttime
--------------------+--------+----------------
2012-05-13 22:24:10 | 404643 | 2012-05-13 22:24:10
2012-05-14 19:38:21 | 404643 | 2012-05-13 22:24:10
2012-07-26 20:31:29 | 219822 | 2012-07-25 19:47:44
```

I use a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) to provide the values, could be a table or function or unnested array or a set generated with [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) something else as well. (Did  you mean `generate_series()` by "generate_sequence()"?)

First I `JOIN` the search timestamps to all rows in the table with earlier or equal `resulttime`. I use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` so that search timestamps are not dropped when there is no prior `resulttime` in the table at all.

With `DISTINCT ON (x.search_ts)` in combination with `ORDER BY x.search_ts, r.resulttime DESC` we get the greatest (or one of the equally greatest) `resulttime` that is smaller or equal to each search timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

A simple subquery to identify the *largest* date within a day boundary from a time series similar to your example would be something like this

```
SELECT max(resulttime), date_trunc('days',resulttime) FROM results GROUP BY 2;
```

that is pinning the timestamp to just the day component using the [date_trunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) function, and then collecting the largest timestamp for each truncated date, using GROUP BY max()

Comment: Thanks, but I believe limiting to just a day will miss the scenario when the closest prior result is on a different day.